# Why my Android's Speech app crashes?

Tags: android

I find a example code here below: it comes from link http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/Core-Class/SamplecodethatinvokesthespeechrecognitionintentAPI.htm

```
/* 
 * Copyright (C) 2008 The Android Open Source Project
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package app.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Sample code that invokes the speech recognition intent API.
 */
public class Test extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private static final int VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE = 1234;

    private ListView mList;

    /**
     * Called with the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Inflate our UI from its XML layout description.
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // Get display items for later interaction
        Button speakButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_speak);

        mList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        // Check to see if a recognition activity is present
        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        List<ResolveInfo> activities = pm.queryIntentActivities(
                new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH), 0);
        if (activities.size() != 0) {
            speakButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        } else {
            speakButton.setEnabled(false);
            speakButton.setText("Recognizer not present");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Handle the click on the start recognition button.
     */
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.btn_speak) {
            startVoiceRecognitionActivity();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Fire an intent to start the speech recognition activity.
     */
    private void startVoiceRecognitionActivity() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Speech recognition demo");
        startActivityForResult(intent, VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    /**
     * Handle the results from the recognition activity.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // Fill the list view with the strings the recognizer thought it could have heard
            ArrayList<String> matches = data.getStringArrayListExtra(
                    RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
            mList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                    matches));
        }

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
//main.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- 
 * Copyright (C) 2008 Google Inc.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 -->

<!-- This activity displays UI for launching voice recognition -->

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="4dip"
        android:text="voice_recognition_prompt" />

    <Button android:id="@+id/btn_speak"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="speak_button" />

    <ListView android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

I copy it to my myeclipse and try to run it but my Galaxy S3 crashes, the error message is below:

```
08-23 00:09:16.975: D/AndroidRuntime(17638): Shutting down VM
08-23 00:09:16.975: W/dalvikvm(17638): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c6f1f8)
08-23 00:09:16.980: E/AndroidRuntime(17638): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-23 00:09:16.980: E/AndroidRuntime(17638): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.voicerecognition/app.test.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: app.test.MainActivity
08-23 00:09:16.980: E/AndroidRuntime(17638):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1894)
08-23 00:09:16.980: E/AndroidRuntime(17638):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1995)
08-23 00:09:16.980: E/AndroidRuntime(17638):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:128)
08-23 00:09:16.980: E/AndroidRuntime(17638):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1161)
08-23 00:09:16.980: E/AndroidRuntime(17638):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-23 00:09:16.980: E/AndroidRuntime(17638):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-23 00:09:16.980: E/AndroidRuntime(17638):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
08-23 00:09:16.980: E/AndroidRuntime(17638):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-23 00:09:16.980: E/AndroidRuntime(17638):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-23 00:09:16.980: E/AndroidRuntime(17638):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
08-23 00:09:16.980: E/AndroidRuntime(17638):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
08-23 00:09:16.980: E/AndroidRuntime(17638):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-23 00:09:16.980: E/AndroidRuntime(17638): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: app.test.MainActivity
08-23 00:09:16.980: E/AndroidRuntime(17638):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
08-23 00:09:16.980: E/AndroidRuntime(17638):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
08-23 00:09:16.980: E/AndroidRuntime(17638):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
08-23 00:09:16.980: E/AndroidRuntime(17638):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1027)
08-23 00:09:16.980: E/AndroidRuntime(17638):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1885)
08-23 00:09:16.980: E/AndroidRuntime(17638):    ... 11 more
```

Could anyone help on it? Thanks!

Comment: The stack trace says it can't find `MainActivity` (whereas the Activity you're launching is called `Test`). Is your project & manifest set up correctly?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you renamed your Activity class to "Test" without changing it in your AndroidManifest.xml.  You probably need to change a line from this:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

To this:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".Test" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```